# Why Android File Chooser with intent action ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT not working on some devices in case file is selected from File Manager?

Tags: android, android-intent, redmi-device

I am trying to select PDF file using intent action ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT on Android but its giving null on some devices.

I want the user to select PDF file only from his device. For this I have used intent action ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

This works correctly in most of the devices but on some of the devices mostly Xiaomi, on file selection it giving null on trying to get the intent data intent.getData() in onActivityResult using the option File Manager as shown in the image below.

I am trying to avoid using action ACTION_GET_CONTENT, since 3rd party apps doesn't restrict the content to pdf only. Other apps are allowing format which is not PDF as well.

[image: file chooser image]

In the image on selecting file from the menu File manager its giving null as intent.getData() but its working fine when i am selecting document from Documents option.

Below is the code for file chooser request

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
intent.setType("application/pdf");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Choose a file"), Constants.FILE_CHOOSER);
```

After file selection

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        final Uri uri = intent.getData(); //Uri is null
    }
}
```

I am expecting some data in intent.getData() but its giving null.

Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=501, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras) }} to activity {com.avail.easyloans.android/com.avail.easyloans.feature.cashup.activities.documents.ActivityUploadBankStmt}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method **'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.getAuthority()' on a null object reference**

What can be the possible error?

Comment: "File Manager" is not part of Android. Either this is an app that you installed, or it is an app that was pre-installed. And, it would appear to have a bug or two.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks. Yes, file manager is pre installed on Xiaomi Redmi 4A. So, Is there any other way to force user to select only PDF files?

Comment: Also, Is there any way to remove this File Manager option from Chooser?

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf, Sure!

Comment: @PrashantJha: "Is there any other way to force user to select only PDF files?" -- there is no guaranteed approach, if that is what you mean. "Is there any way to remove this File Manager option from Chooser?" -- I would start by yelling at Xiaomi, as they should not be implementing `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`. After that... a risky approach would be to use `setPackage()` on the `Intent` to limit it to the OS documents UI. I don't remember what that application ID is, and I am uncertain if it will be consistent across all Android devices. So, I would focus on defensive programming and live with it.